# How to store data to redis at specific Time interval in Go

Tags: go, redis, beego, data-caching

I am trying to Set Data to Redis at (6 am, 12 pm, 6 pm and 12 am). But all I can do is setting an expiration time for data caching in redis. Is there any way in Golang to do this?

Code:

```
err := client.Set(key, data[]byte, 6 * time.Hour).Err()
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to set some data every 6 hours starting at 6am. Why not use [cron.jobs](https://github.com/robfig/cron) for this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to add data in redis at evry 6 hours. You should use cronjob for this.

I have created a sample scenario which might help you as follows:

For better understanding you can refer [gocron](https://github.com/go-co-op/gocron) package.

```
s := gocron.NewScheduler(time.UTC)
    
    s.Every(6).Hours().Do(func(){  //you can change it
    
      err := client.Set(ctx, "key", "value", 0).Err()  //your logic
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    
     })
```

Comment: How can I start the scheduler at 6 am everyday and runs it every 6 hours later so that I can get data at 6 am, 12 pm, 6 pm and 12 am?

Comment: you can pass it inside `Scheduler` Refer : https://github.com/go-co-op/gocron/blob/c3be44d54fb58382559e16160de33ab222916ac4/scheduler.go#L43